# Request failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

This is my data that is available in an api call. I've checked it using Postman.

```
[
  {
    "senderId": "IYD6TM7BDDGRUS4",
    "receiverId": "HXJC6TM7BGAQRUS4",
    "mediaId": "22797361348"
  },
  {
    "senderId": "YGG4FIHXJC6TM7",
    "receiverId": "JC6TM7BDDGARUS4",
    "mediaId": "22797361348"
  }

]
```

This is the function that I'm using to get this array,

```
export function fetchMessages(url){
  return fetch(url, { credentials : 'include', mode: 'no-cors'})
        .then((response) => {
          //console.log("Request successful: ", response.text());
          return response.json(); })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            let messages = [];
            for(let i=0; i< data.length; i++){
                let message = new Message(data[i].senderId, data[i].receiverId, data[i].mediaId);
                messages.push(message);
            }
        return messages;
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log("Request failed: ", error);
         });
}
```

Firstly I get the following error,

When I run this I get the following,

```
Request failed:  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

And when I try to print the array objects I get undefined. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: As a note, you can't call `response.text()` and then `response.json()`, you can only call once, but when the first `console.log` is commented out, it looks like it should work, the only reason it wouldn't, is if the data isn't valid JSON, but what you've posted is valid.

Comment: End of input usually means your missing braces or parentheses

Comment: this isn't a cross origin request is it?

Comment: Both the server and the client are running locally.

Comment: Make sure the  requested json url has a Content-Type header of `text/plain` and not `text/html`